# RDLC Partial Formatting

Tags: .net, reporting, rdlc

[image: Sample Report Img]

Hi friends, I need to apply partial formatting (mainly bold) to the fields of a table.  I create the datatable dynamically and apply it to the rdlc report.  I use VS2010 and .Net 4.0.  I have seen on the net suggestions to use html placeholders, but could not find a good tutorial.  Any help is appreciated.  I have included a sample image of what I would like to achieve, where each row is data from a datatable row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not difficult with html syntax.

The string (from the source) must be something like this:

`The patient should take aspirin <b>325 mg</b>`

In the placeholder properties, you have to check the `HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles` option.

[Here the steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627491.aspx) from msdn library